# JavaFx ComboBox. Временно отключить выпадающий список

Tags: javafx, combobox

Пытаюсь сделать некий редактор.
На нынешнем этапе одна из проблем - выпадающий список комбобокса.
Сделал так - комбобоксу добавил обработчик MouseClick, который создает вокруг него рамку для изменения размеров. Но, естественно, сам комбобокс при клике на нем открывает свой выпадающий список. Получается так:
[image: combobox]

Можно ли временно отключить список?

Answer (score 1):

Удалось найти решение с использованием EventDispatcher:

```
comboBox.setEventDispatcher(new EventDispatcher(){
    public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain edc) {
        if(event.getEventType().getName().equals("MOUSE_CLICKED")){
            // Тут любые действия...
            // comboBox может получить фокус.
            comboBox.requestFocus(); 
            // При этом показ списка comboBox не происходит.
        }
        return event;
    }});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Использовать метод setDisable() :

```
public class SampleComboBox extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label testLbl = new Label("Combo box:");
        ComboBox<String> testBox = new ComboBox<>();
        testBox.getItems().addAll("one", "two", "three", "four");

        Label selectionLbl = new Label("current");

        testBox.setOnAction(e->{
            selectionLbl.setText(testBox.getValue());
        });

        // выключение ComboBox ------------------------
        CheckBox isDisable = new CheckBox("off");
        isDisable.setOnAction(e->{
            // суть  -  setDisable() 
            testBox.setDisable(isDisable.selectedProperty().getValue());
        });
        // ------------------------------------------

        HBox row1 = new HBox(10, testLbl, testBox);
        VBox root = new VBox(10, row1, selectionLbl, isDisable);

        root.setSpacing(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Using ComboBox Controls");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не то, что требуется. В таком варианте comboBox не может получать фокус.

Comment: @micom В таком случае уточните Ваш вопрос. "временно отключить" звучит не однозначно

Comment: Согласен, я не корректно сформулировал вопрос. Вопрос в следующем: как сделать, чтобы я мог его кликать, а он получать фокус, но при этом выпадающий список бы не появлялся.
Только что пришла идея, что нужно унаследоваться от комбобокса и как-то переопределить событие клика.

Comment: @micom Нужно ли предлагать альтернативные методы решения? Покажите свою реализацию, что Вы предприняли, что не работает?